# OData: how to get the highest ID in UI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have an OData service that delivers all entries from a table. Every row has its own ID. I am trying to get the highest ID and assign it to a variable in my application.

This is my JS code, in which I'm ordering all entries by `Id` and making a top, to have only one.

```js
oModel.read("/ZDEMA_LENDINGS2Set?$orderby=Id desc &$top=1", {
  success: function(oData, oResponse) {
    console.log("Data", oData);
    console.log("Response", oResponse);
    //data = oModel.getProperty("/ID");
```

The results look like this:

[image: results of my OData feed request]

I don't know how to access it. I only want to have the highest ID. With `getProperty`, I had no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to get the highest ID

One of the solutions would be to make use of `$top=1` together with **descending** `$orderby`. E.g.: [https://.../Northwind.svc/Products?**$orderby=ProductID desc&$top=1**&$format=json](https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$orderby=ProductID%20desc&$top=1&$format=json)

In UI5 with `v2.ODataModel`, it could look something like this:

```js
myODataModel.read("/Products", {
  sorters: [
    new Sorter("ProductID", /*descending*/true) // "Sorter" required from "sap/ui/model/Sorter"
  ],
  urlParameters: {
    "$select": "ProductID",
    "$top": 1,
  },
  success: function(data) {
    const highestProdId = data.results[0].ProductID;
    // ...
  },
});
```

- `$top=1` eliminates the need to loop through the feed clientside, reducing the data load
- `$orderby=... desc` pushes the corresponding entity to the top
- `$select=...` in addition requests only the required property within the entity type, reducing the data load further.

Comment: This will only work if the OData service implements the relevant URL parameters (which is obviously not the case)

Comment: @Marc That's true. However, the actual issue that the question author has, is the invalid use of the `.read` API. Even if the mentioned system queries are implemented in the service, adding those to the `sPath` as the 1st arg won't have any effects. The answer here provides a possible fix for this.

Answer (score -1):

this is the solution

```
            oModel.read("/ZDEMA_LENDINGS2Set?$orderby=Id desc", {
                urlParameters: {
                    "$select": "Id",
                    "$top": 1
                },

                success: function(oData, oResponse) {
                    console.log("Data", oData);
                    console.log("Response", oResponse);

                    var highestId = oData.results[0].Id;
                    console.log(highestId);

                },
                error: function(oError) {
                    console.log("Error", oError);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please avoid adding queries manually to the `sPath`. It's an anti-pattern and ignoring the [`read`-API](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/read) contract which is anything but future-proof. In this case, `sorters: [ /*Sorter instance*/ ]` should be used instead of adding `$orderby` manually as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59643310/5846045

Comment: Thank you i Changed it to  sorters: [
  new sap.ui.model.Sorter("Id", true)
 ],
 urlParameters: {
  "$select": "Id"
  //"$top": 1
 },